# What tense for "had been living" or "had lived"

Tags: past-tense

This is an original sentence: "Who had been living in this house before they pulled it down?"

Can we say "Who had lived in this house before they pulled it down?" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it means that the people who had been living there before the house was pulled down lived there until the house was pulled down, so they were the last residents of the house, whereas the people who had lived there before the house was pulled down could be anyone who had ever lived in that house. That includes people who lived there years ago. If a duration is mentioned, like for example "10 years", both had been living and had lived are interchangeable.